# Is there a Factory Defaults / Reset pin on the WIZnet W7500P-S2E IC?

Tags: integrated-circuit, ethernet

I want to use the [W7500P-S2E](https://docs.wiznet.io/Product/Pre-programmed-MCU/W7500P-S2E/w7500p-s2e-EN) IC for a device with a serial interface, that I want to make accessible through the network.

The "-S2E" variant of the W7500P is the same chip, except it's been pre-loaded with the the "S2E" firmware.
This firmware is normally shipped on the W7500P chips used in the "W7500S2E" modules (those are small PCBs with the "W7500(P) on them, with the aforementioned S2E firmware").

Now in the [datasheet](https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/443/WIZnet_12032019_W7500S2E-1673019.pdf) (or "manual" as they call it), there is a `DEFAULT` pin mentioned (Page 47, section "8.3 Factory Reset through Module Pin"). Unfortunately, the datasheet (or manual) doesn't say to what pin on the IC this pin is routed to, or if there is some form of extra circuity on the board to generate some sort of reset signal, etc.:
[image: W7500S2E manual, section 8.3 "Reset By Hardware" / "Factory Reset through module Pin"]

Does someone perhaps have the board and could tell me how this pin is attached to the IC on the eval board, and if there's some extra circuity between the module's `DEFAULT` pin and whatever IC-pin this goes to?

My only reference to go by, is one of the pictures in their online shop:
[image]
However the pin that I'm interested in (double sided row, inner line, center pin) isn't visibly routed to any of the IC pins in this picture.

Any of the other products in their product range don't have decent enough PCB design files, that I could use as a reference. They also mention the W7500(P)-S2E stand-alone IC (with firmware, but not on one of their modules), however that product variant isn't mentioned in their manual, at all (it's mentioned in the product range table, but then not discussed anywhere else in the document).

Some of the wording they use is quite confusing; some of the names they use have a little of a naming-collision going on ("W7500S2E" is a module, while "W7500-S2E" is just the IC with a firmware programmed from the factory, etc.), Some of the datasheets / manuals of the same part are different, but have the same version number (there are two "W7500S2E User Manual V1.1.1" one containing the Product "W7500S2E-S1", the other doesn't. The former is actually version 1.2, except the PDF reports being "W7500S2E User Manual V1.1.1.docx").

If I can't figure out where this `DEFAULT` pin is on the through gathering information like that, I guess the only other step would be to get one of the modules and reverse-engineer it.

Naming one pin `RESET` the other `DEFAULT` and then referring to "Factory Reset", and having several "Reset variants" kinda adds to the confusion, and is a little unintuitive -- it takes some time getting used to the "datasheets" (which are actually sales-infosheets) and "manuals" (which are the actual datasheets).

Comment: Did you look at page 5 (2.1.2 W7500S2E-R1 pinout and pin definition) and page 8 (W7500S2E-Z1 reference schematic)?

Comment: @StainlessSteelRat well, yes, that's what I was referencing in my post! The pins are pertaining to the modules, they don't say to which pin on the IC those are routes. The chip is pre-loaded with the S2E firmware, so I'm absolutely sure that pin is also available on their "W7500S2E-C1" (page 1) product which is just the chip. However that pinout isn't described in the datasheet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[W7500S2E-C1 Reference Schematic](https://www.wizse.com/w7500s2e/#)

[image]

Pin 9 (Default) goes to Pin 54 on W7500S2E-C1.  This corresponds to upper image.

[image]

[W7500S2E series](https://www.wizse.com/w7500s2e/)

I am unsure about the second image.  But that site will give you what you want.

[W7500S2E-R1](https://docs.wiznet.io/Product/S2E-Module/W7500S2E-R1)

Comment: Yeah, I just found it yesterday... Thanks anyways, but it's still kinda "meh" the way they structured their documentation...

Comment: The remaining question is, whether the W7500P-S2E and W7500-S2E have the `DEFAULT` ping in the same location...

Comment: It's not a true datasheet because it is a programmed STM32F1 (not sure on the 1).  If you check it out, it is the BOOT pin, which would apply to all.

Comment: WIZnet chips are STM32Fx? Never would've guessed that!